# Does Android put wifi and other data networks to sleep when the display is turned off?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, screen

I was wondering if stock Android puts Wifi and other data networks to sleep when the display of the device is turned off. If not, what app can help me do the same ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends, some Android devices have an advanced setting **WiFi Sleep Policy** under

`Settings -> Wireless -> Wi-Fi Settings -> [Menu Button] Advanced -> Wi-Fi Sleep Policy`

But I am not sure if this is a vanilla Android feature or an manufacturer modification. At least the Galaxy S series has this setting.

Data networks are usually fully active. But Apps like Tasker allow you to define certain profiles to improve battery life. For example: Only allow 2G when the display is off, because 2G requires less battery then 3G (UMTS).

Comment: That too on menu button... I wonder if there are any other settings with more options on menu buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it turns the WiFi or Data networks off. You can try by downloading an app from market and while it is downloading, turn off the  screen. You can see that even after the screen is off, the download completes after some time. I am not sure exactly which app does this but you can try searching the market for such an app.

Comment: Whoever is down voting the answer, i would request to please provide a comment as to why the answer was downvoted.

Comment: Pretty cumbersome answer as there is setting built in Android for exactly what OP describes.

Comment: The WiFi sleep policy describes when to switch from WiFi to Mobile Data for my Samsung Galaxy S. Kiran is asking about whether WiFi or Mobile Data (connection to a network) gets lost or not. This is little bit different from WiFi Sleep Policy. Further, there is no such policy for Mobile Data.

Comment: I'd down vote this answer due to following statements presented in answer: 1) "you can try searching the market for such an app" --not helpful, if you know some of them, name it here 2) "you can design one yourself. This wouldn't be hard" --I really don't think so.

Comment: Removed the designing part. That would correct it somewhat.